# Android App Engine Module cannot find AppCompat Library

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I recently added an App Engine Module to my app while following this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/helloendpoints-android-studio

My EndpointsAsyncTask (Inside the App Engine Module) looks like this:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import     com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Pair;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.naming.Context;


class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void,  String> {
    private static MyApi myApiService = null;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            MyApi.Builder builder = new     MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                // options for running against local devappserver
                // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
        // end options for devappserver

        myApiService = builder.build();
    }

    context = params[0].first;
    String name = params[0].second;

    try {
        return myApiService.sayHi(name).execute().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I get 'Cannot resolve symbol/method' errors for AsyncTask, .build(), .sayHi() and Toast, just to mention a few.

I started tying to figure out what the problem was and realised the imports for those pats weren't there. So, I tied adding:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

and then carried on from there. Unfortunately, though, those also gave me errors.

So, I looked in my build.gradle file and realised that the AppCompat dependency wasn't there.

My build.gradle for the app engine module looks like this:

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.34'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'

    }

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

Now, when building my project it gives the error:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1
```

Am I missing something in terms of the way the app engine module works or is my problem not AppCompat? In the messages window it gives me the option to 'Install Repository and sync poject but when I click that, nothing happens.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what is your compile SDK version?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25, 
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1", classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' (project gradle file).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I've figured out what the problem is. My EndpointsAsyncTask is meant to be in the App module and not the AppEngine one. If anyone could verify this I would appreciate it!

I hope this helps anyone else that may be confused by the tutorial.